# Non white lines on 1920x180 LVDS controlled TFT

Tags: lcd, display, lvds, tft

We are integrating a LVDS 27" 1920x1080 panel with a commercial DVI to LVDS controller board.
We have a PC, that has a DVI output, and we connect it to the Video controller.

The video controller it is 12V powered, and has a 350mm LVDS cable connected to the TFT. This LVDS cable it is a good quality one, has a protective earth screen, and it is connected to the ground on the video controller. All the LVDS pairs are correctly twisted.

The backlight of the TFT has an external DC/DC converter, that provides the current to the backlight (the leds of the backlight of the display had a different connector).

We have the screen on portrait mode (turned 90º).

What it is happening us it is that sometimes, when we switch on the system, we have some white vertical lines on the screen. There are not real vertical lines, it is like a ghosting effect. From my point of view it looks like a scanning error, so the pictures are blurred because some vertical lines are not drawn on their right position.

This effect lasts until we switch off the video controller and the TFT for about 10 seconds. After waitint, we are able to provide again power to the system and it starts working again.

When this happens, we are able to see this effect with the "OSD Video controller info" that appears for some seconds. It allways shows the text 1920x180 60Hz, but this text it is not correctly shown when this problems arises. So, we think that the problem it is not caused by the PC.

We have tried to reproduce the problem switching off and on the complete system using a relay for hundreds of times, or changing the position of the cables, without being  lucky enough to be able to reproduce it.

We have also tried to remove the protective earth on the LVDS cable, or to make this cable longer, without being  lucky enough to be able to reproduce it.

Any suggestion of what it is happening well be very helpful!

As a picture it is a lot better than a thousand works, please have some reference pictures:

[image: Text with ghosting]

[image: OSD information when failing]

[image: OSD information when showing OK]

Comment: Do you have another panel you can try?

Comment: This has happenned us with a total of 4 different TFT panels, and with different DVI-LVDS controllers. When we try to reproduce on our lab it happens very few times, but on the final application it seems to be happening more easily.

Comment: This may be a sync issue. Are you using the same video source in the application as in the lab?

Comment: We are using exactly the same video source, it is a DVI 1920x1080 60Hz Signal and this is what it seems to detect the controller board. Maybe it could be a sync issue between the controller and the TFT.

Today we have been trying to provide separate power to the LVDS panel using a lab power supply. The current it is around 0,5 Amps. If we have less than 4.5 Volts, the image it is not currenty shown and the TFT starts making a strange noise, but allways, when we provide again 5V, the picture recovers without problems.

Any suggestion of how we can try to reproduce it?